# Add links to slider banners

Tags: html, slider, banner

I have slider banners on my homepage that don't link to anywhere. What code do I need to add links for each image? Is it possible with the code below?:

```
Thank you! I need to add a different link to each banner. The banners are all going to the   printf('<a href="yourlink.html"> link. What am I doing wrong? <div id="home">
    <div class="banner">
        <div class="banner-slider">
            <?php
                if (!empty($options['slider_photo'])):
                    $slider_photos = explode(',', $options['slider_photo']);

                    foreach ($slider_photos as $k => $img):
                        printf('<a href="http://www.nemotile.com/tile/product/Handwritten/"><div class="banner-%d" style="background-image:url(%s)"></div></a>', $k, $img);
                    endforeach;
                else: ?>

                    <a href="http://www.nemotile.com/tile/product/Handwritten/"><div class="banner-1"></div></a>
                    <a href="http://www.nemotile.com/tile/product/patchwork/"><div class="banner-2"></div>
                    <a href="http://www.nemotile.com/tile/product/BisazzaCementTiles/"><div class="banner-3"></div>
                    <div class="banner-5"></div>
                <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change this code to the excerpt below. Using $i you can step up through your URL array, this should give you the general process for it. I'm unsure on how you are getting the URL's but this should take you down the right path.

```html
<div class="banner">
    <div class="banner-slider">
        <?php
        $urls = ['URL1', 'URL2', 'URL3', 'URL4'];
        $i = 0;

        if (!empty($options['slider_photo'])):
            $slider_photos = explode(',', $options['slider_photo']);

            foreach ($slider_photos as $k => $img):
                printf('<a href="'.$urls[$i].'"><div class="banner-%d" style="background-image:url(%s)"></div></a>', $k, $img);
                $i++;
            endforeach;
        else: ?>

        <a href="http://www.nemotile.com/tile/product/Handwritten/"><div class="banner-1"></div></a>
        <a href="http://www.nemotile.com/tile/product/patchwork/"><div class="banner-2"></div>
            <a href="http://www.nemotile.com/tile/product/BisazzaCementTiles/"><div class="banner-3"></div>
                <div class="banner-5"></div>
                <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I need to add a different link to each banner

Comment: @SophieMitchell please mark this as the correct answer so I get credit for it.